# Blitz tournaments (time control around 5 minutes)

Tags: blitz

I want to know if any of you could help me finding results from strong Blitz tournaments where the time control is around 5 minutes per player. It's for research. I do not have Chessbase or any chess game data base. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Blitz_Chess_Championship
>
> By 1950, the time controls had changed to the familiar five minutes per player, hence the "five-minute game" moniker; the term "blitz chess" would not be coined until the 1960s.

Please search the games on Chessgames. You don't need Chessbase.

Comment: I found them here: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?tid=92132 but to download the PGNs I need to pay for an entire year. I only want to get those games. Do you have a premium chessgames account?

Comment: @VladimirVargas Can you do programming? https://github.com/student-t/ExtractPGN

Comment: wow, that really saved me some time! Thanks a lot. Already downloading that! :-D